# Ubuntu 16.04 virtualenv django import error

Tags: django, ubuntu-16.04, importerror

I installed django at virtualenv. 
Django is installed at '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', but that's not virtualenv's python path. so that makes django import error in virtualenv. 
please help

Comment: did you activate the virtualenv?

Comment: Can you update the question with the stacktrace?Like from the line Traceback to the last line

Answer (score 2):

You should always install libraries within your virtualenv. Activate it and then do `pip install django` again.